# Custom Magento module config.xml not loading after applying security patch

Tags: magento-1.9, product, module, configuration, patches

I've just applied the security patches on Magento 1.9 and after that, my custom modules didn't work. I tried clearing the cache and index but nothing happened. When I tried visiting the URL of my custom module, it says 404 not found.

I tried this

```
die(Mage::app()->getConfig()->getNode()->asXML());
```

to check if my config.xml was there but it wasn't.

Here's my app/code/local/Custom/Product/etc/config.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Custom_Product>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Custom_Product>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <customproductview>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Custom_Product</module>
                <frontName>customproductview</frontName>
            </args>
        </customproductview>
    </routers>
</frontend>
</config>
```

Here's my app/etc/modules/Custom_Product.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <modules>
    <Custom_Product>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Custom_Product>
 </modules>
</config>
```

Is there anyone who experienced this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell us which patch you have applied? To check whether your module is properly enabled you must check the **app\etc\modules\Custom_Product.xml** for its status. Or you can remove its entry from **core_resource** table , clear the cache and check it again.

Comment: There's no entry on the core_resource because I didn't use any SQL on this module. Also, we installed all the patches required for the Magento 1.9.1.0. Here's the list. http://prntscr.com/k45e26. Thank you!

Comment: Make some typo mistake in your module's XML, reload frontend. Then check for the log files under **`/var/log`** folder in Magento. If the module is being read, you should see errors for the typo in logs.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora I already did your suggestion but I didn't see any errors related to my module. Does it mean even my Custom_Product.xml is not loading? But when I go to Configuration > Advanced, I can see it from the list. Nothing happened though even if I enable or disable it.

Comment: @nosnevetzy, loading module under Configuration > Advanced means that Custom_Product.xml is working fine. Nothing else.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora then what should I do? :( I rename app/code/local/Mage folder so that it will not overwrite the core files which has the updated files since I just applied the security patches but still 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so what I did is I transfer the module from app/code/local to app/code/community and change the Custom_Product.xml

```
<codePool>community</codePool>
```

Thanks for all the help!